# Combine two columns from two statements into single result-set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

MS SQL Server 2008

I have two `SELECT` statements

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Number_of_SEP11_clients
FROM
...
WHERE 
...
and dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%11.%'



SELECT COUNT(*) as Number_of_SEP12_clients
FROM
...
WHERE 
...
and dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%12.%'
```

Output is

```
Number_of_SEP11_clients
109111
```

and

```
Number_of_SEP12_clients
44812
```

How to make the output

```
Number_of_SEP11_clients    Number_of_SEP12_clients
       109111                        44812
```

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with Powershell?

Comment: @EBGreen it was typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can do a `cross join` to get what you want, I am going to guess that the `FROM` and rest of the `WHERE` clauses are the same.  In that case, just do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%11.%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Number_of_SEP11_clients,
       SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%12.%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Number_of_SEP12_clients,

FROM
...
WHERE 
...
```

If you like, you can add:

```
WHERE . . . AND
      (dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%11.%' or dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%12.%')
```

Answer (score 1):

This could depend on your table structure, but you can do this with a couple of subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
...
WHERE 
...
and dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%11.%') AS Number_of_SEP11,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
...
WHERE 
...
and dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%12.%') AS Number_of_SEP12;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option ..

```
SELECT Number_of_SEP11_clients, Number_of_SEP12_clients
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 as ID, COUNT(*) as Number_of_SEP11_clients
    FROM
    ...
    WHERE 
    ...
    and dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%11.%'
) SEP11CLIENT
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1 as ID, COUNT(*) as Number_of_SEP12_clients
    FROM
    ...
    WHERE 
    ...
    and dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%12.%'
) SEPT12CLIENT
ON SEPT11CLIENT.ID = SEPT12CLIENT.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number_of_SEP11_clients
        FROM
        ...
        WHERE 
        ...
        and dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%11.%') AS Clients_SEP11,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number_of_SEP12_clients
        FROM
       ...
       WHERE 
       ...
       and dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION like '%12.%') AS Clients_SEP12;
```